# ASP.NET MVC and Angular 1.5 architecture and responsibilities separation

Tags: c#, angularjs, architecture, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing, with a colleague of mine, a web application with ASP.NET MVC 5 (just MVC from now on) and Angular 1.5. 
I would use **MVC** purely as *backend* actor: exposing APIs and interacting with the database, without generating any view. **Angular**, on the other side, will be responsible of the whole client side, using components and templates for the view, routing and services to call the MVC endpoints.
I thnk this would bring a clear separation of responsibilities and a neat architecture. However my colleague would prefer to keep MVC routing, generate views from the server and "injecting" Angular into them, hence using it as *client side* business logic. This would bring some other benefits as the possibility to speed up some security measures (eg. by using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`). This, though, would make it harder to use angular components and the new components pattern.
Of course a different approach can be to use WebApi only as backend and maintain a clear cut, but I am curious to hear from others how they tackled the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is for creating single page applications, following your colleague approach would mean to have one single page application per route, which would break the purpose of single page applications. SPA's takes some time to load, if you have one SPA per route you would pay the load time for every route, and because its a new page you lose the state of the previous page.

Anti forgery tokens are also possible in angular applications see [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#cross-site-request-forgery-xsrf-protection).

We create angular applications in our company, we use web api, and just two razor pages, one for login and one for the spa application. It would be possible to have just index.html, but having the login page separated brings some simplicity, and injecting some intitial data into the main page simplifies angular bootstraping.

Comment: having the login page rendered by MVC is for more practical purposes (closer to authentication service)? Otherwise, why not having it also provided by angular and calling the backend via API?

Comment: It's also simpler. The logic is already implemented at server side, if you try to go to the main page and you are not authenticated you are redirected to the login page, when you login, you are redirected to the main page to the route you wanted to go in the first place. If you want to have the login in the SPA you have to implement that logic in your SPA. The login page is very light weight, so what is the benefit of implementing it in the SPA?

Comment: There are some complexities to implement authentication in Angular. When angular bootstraps you need to know if the user is authenticated. Angular can be bootstrapped in any route, and even when the user press F5. The user is authenticated if the authentication cookie is present, but you cannot access the authentication cookie, it's http only, so you need to call a web api end point to get the current user, but in angular it's not very easy to wait for http calls on bootstrapping. So I prefer the server side approach

Comment: Thanks for describing your approach, it is very useful. I will leave the question open for some days to gather some more opinions/inputs before accepting it.